# Laravel 5.1: How to pass HTML Body and Text Body without using view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, html-email, sendmail

I'm trying to send emails in laravel5.1 and found that Mail:Send used view templates like below:

```
Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);
```

Problem is I have my ready to send HTML body and TEXT body are coming from database. How to set html view and text view if content coming from database like below:

```
$html_body = $row['Html_Body']; // holds html content
$text_body = $row['Text_Body']; // holds text content
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attach text/plain message we can use addParts method like below

```
$message->to($email_details['to'])
->subject($email_details['subject'])
->from($email_details['from'])
->setBody($email_details['html'], 'text/html');

/* add alternative parts with addPart()*/
$message->addPart($email_details['text'], 'text/plain');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
Mail::send(['text' => $text_body], $data, $callback);
```

Comment: How about HTML? Can i add Mail::send(['text' => $text_body,'html'=>$html_body], $data, $callback);

Comment: text is the variable containing the text that will be sent, so you would have to concatenate both of your variables,

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your data to your view like this

```
$data = [];
$data['Html_Body'];
$data['Text_Body'];
\Mail::send('html.view', $data , function($message)
{
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
});
```

and use the data you passed to the view as variables

```
$Html_Body;
$Text_Body;
```

Comment: i don't want to use any view. That is what i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mailBody = View::make('my_mail', ['name' => 'fknight']);
    $contents = (string) $mailBody;
    // or
    $contents = $mailBody->render();
```

this is the better way instead of using plain html in variable